# Java thread pool with single thread not behaving as expected

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I am creating a Thread pool executer with just one thread and using Kotlin's asCoroutineDispatcher() method in a Kotlin program. When I launch multiple coroutines from a loop and log the Thread name, I see different names - pool1-thread1, pool3-thread1, pool9-thread-1 etc.
Why there are multiple threads when I used single thread for the pool?
Does Kotlin manages thread pool differently?

```
// this is executed in loop
fun executeTask(url: String) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val result = runAsync(url)
        Log.d("coroutineCheck", "$url\t\tStatus:$result")
    }
}
//some blocking n/w IO goes in this method
//I log the thread name here
suspend fun runAsync(url: String): String = withContext(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher()) {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `newFixedThreadPool` every time you call your method, repeatedly creating brand new pools.

You will want to share the same Executor.

```
// singleton to put somewhere, may also need to shut it down eventually
val dispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher()

suspend func runAsync(url: String): String = withContext(dispatcher){ ... }
```

Comment: Adding on - The naming convention pool{N}-thread-{M} basically means, that the thread is the Mth thread from the Nth pool created. Eg- pool9-thread-1 means it is the first thread of the 9th pool.